# Error trying to stream Rasperry Pi RTSP Camera to OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, streaming, rtsp

I have tried everything and looked through the answers on here... I thought it was something wrong with my `ffmpeg` library though I've done countless re-installs of `OpenCV` and am now using it through Anaconda Python 2.7.

I am trying to get a Raspberry Pi camera stream working through OpenCV VideoCapture so I can do OpenCV face tracking with it on Windows. I am able to play the live stream in VLC as well as play test AVI videos and open images so I don't think there is anything wrong with the OpenCV build or ffmpeg?

The error I am getting is

> rtsp @ ............. method SETUP failed: 461 Client error.

The code I am trying to run is simple, this is the IP of my Pi and the stream filename was set to `x`:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.106:8554/x")

while(1):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv.waitKey(1)
```

I have also uploaded the error screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Can someone please help this simple thing is doing my head in!

Comment: Please include the error messages as text and not as an image.

Comment: [rtsp @ 00000000003e9860] method SETUP failed: 461 Client er
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/s
pp:779)
warning: rtsp://192.168.1.106:8554/x (/build/opencv/modules/
eg_impl.hpp:780)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>
le C:\bld\opencv_1498157567167\work\opencv-3.2.0\modules\hig
 line 304
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blink_detection4.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
cv2.error: C:\bld\opencv_1498157567167\work\opencv-3.2.0\mod
dow.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in